# Updating object value in core data is also creating a new object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have check the following Q&A and while the solutions are much the same the issue remains for me remains:
[Saving an updated Core Data instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766823/saving-an-updated-core-data-instance?lq=1)

[Update/Edit coreData managed object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343360/update-edit-coredata-managed-object)

[How to update existing object in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data)

I have a log in/log out feature in my app.

The Core Data entity "NewLog" has the following attributes

```
String loginTime
String logoutTime
String loginStatus
String name
```

When I login it creates a new object in the core data. When I log out I have the object update.The issue is when I logout it updates the existing object but creates a new object also.

Here is my "save" code from my super class so that I don't have to continuously rewrite it and risk errors in my classes:

```
- (void) saveAndDismiss{

    NSError * error = nil;
    if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]){
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save: &error]){
            NSLog(@"Save Failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Save Successful");
        }
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

In my loginViewController implementation file to update the "loginStatus" and "logoutTime":

```
- (IBAction)logOutButton:(id)sender {

    //access the managed object context and create a shortcut name
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    //refer to the entity in the core data
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"NewLog" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //create a request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity: entity];

    // Results should be in descending order of loginTime.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"loginTime" ascending:NO];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];

    //create an array of results
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL];
    NewLog *latestEntity = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    //refer to the specific value that I wish to change
    NSString * statusOfLogin = latestEntity.loginStatus;

    //if the loginStatus in my app is currently YES
    if ([statusOfLogin isEqual:@"YES"]){

        //create a date formatter
        NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

        //format as such
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy , HH:mm:ss"];

        //convert to a string
        NSString *dateInStringFormated=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

        //hide logout button and display login button
        _logOutButton.alpha = 0.0;
        _loginButtonStatus.alpha = 1.0;

        //status declared as String in .h file
        status = @"NO";

        //update the object found in "latestEntity"
        latestEntity.logoutTime = dateInStringFormated;
        //set the login status to be NO
        latestEntity.loginStatus = status;

        //BOOL declared in the .h file
        logStatus = false;


        self.loginLabel.text = @"Logged Out";
        self.dateLabel.text = dateInStringFormated;

        [super saveAndDismiss];

    }

}
```

When I save the updated data it creates a new object containing only the logoutTime and loginStatus.

Is there a solution to stop the new object being created?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know that it is creating a new object the following ways:
 1. The SQL file displays the new object with the content stated above - logoutTime and loginStatus
 2. The tableview displays the new object and in the detail view for it displays the two items.

Checking the area it's coming from is my segue:

```
//prepare for segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    //first check whether the segue is equal to our transition name
    if([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"])
    {
        //tell the segue where to go
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;

        //create reference to view controller
        LoginViewController *loginVC= (LoginViewController*) navigationController.topViewController;

        //create the new object
        NewLog *addLogDetails = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewLog" inManagedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext]];

        loginVC.logEntry = addLogDetails;
    }
}
```

I know why it's creating a new object but how do I prevent this from happening while remaining able to save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the code in your question is creating a new managed object, so either the problem is elsewhere in your code or you're mistaken that an extra object is being created - you don't say how you have come to this conclusion.

To identify the problem, implement `awakeFromInsert` on your `NewLog` object and add a breakpoint. This will be hit every time one of these objects is added, you can then examine the stack trace to find out where the object is being added from.

**UPDATE**

OK, having done that, you see that you're making a new entity every time the segue is performed. Don't do that. You need to perform a fetch to find the existing login object, and only if there isn't one, or the existing one isn't suitable, create a new one.

If you do a fetch and there's nothing in the array, `objectAtIndex:0` will crash. Use `firstObject` instead and check if the result of that is nil.

Comment: I know it's creating a new object because I check the SQL file each time I run and test and the tableview also displays the new object as well as the detail view displaying the details as I mention: "When I save the updated data it creates a new object containing only the logoutTime and loginStatus.". I wouldn't have posted this question otherwise. I will try your suggestion of using the awakeFromInsert though.

Comment: fetch and check the the count sql file if not your ref point while using core data

Comment: Found that the segue was the issue in my next view controllers class. I know why it's creating a new object now however how can I prevent it while still being able to save the updated information?

Comment: Do you have some code that I could try for this at all? I have tried my way which was working fine while I had objects in core data however testing without any objects throws the error message because "objectsAtIndex: 0" is no longer correct. 

I have tried "if([statusOfLogin isEqual:@"NO"] || latestEntity == nil)" however this is still throwing errors with the same issue that the index is referencing 0.

Comment: Also, not the only code I have tried, thought I should make that clear. Always the same message, which makes sense that I am referencing objectAtIndex: 0, however when I am not directly referencing, I don't know why it's throwing errors.

Comment: If there's nothing in the array, objectAtIndex:0 will crash. Use `firstObject` instead and check if the result of that is nil

Comment: @jrturton Throw that in your answer mate, I will give it the vote :-) Works perfect now. Thanks for your patience and your help.